# Unstable connection from Honor 8x to microchip rn4020 Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, microchip

Here is programm to connect to rn4020 bluetooth module.
My code is fine work at Honor 9 device its fast connection and stable.
But its very long time to connect from Honor 8x and sometimes its connect only the third-fifth time. I can upload all project to github if it's necessary.

Here is connection

```java
android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback scanCallback =
    new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, final ScanResult result) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {                                              
            @Override
            public void run() {
            if(result.getDevice().getName()!=null){
                if(!devs.contains(result.getDevice().getName())) {
                    devs.add(result.getDevice().getName());
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            if(!devices_adress.contains(result.getDevice())) {
                if(result.getDevice().getName()!=null) {
                    devices_adress.add(result.getDevice());
                    String dev_temp = result.getDevice().getName();
                try {
                    if(number_dev.contains(bonded_devise)){
                        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                        mBluetoothGatt = result.getDevice().connectGatt(getContext(), true, mGattCallback);
                        mBluetoothGatt.connect();
                        bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(scanCallback);
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Log.w("err1",e.getMessage());
                }

                }

            }
            }
            });
        }
    };
```

And then I waiting to find all services and start transmition

```java
private void findMldpGattService(List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices) {
        if (gattServices == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "findMldpGattService found no Services");
            return;
        }
        String uuid;


        for (BluetoothGattService gattService : gattServices) {
            uuid = gattService.getUuid().toString();
            if (uuid.equals(MLDP_PRIVATE_SERVICE)) {
                List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics = gattService.getCharacteristics();
                for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic : gattCharacteristics) {
                    uuid = gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString();
                    if (uuid.equals(MLDP_DATA_PRIVATE_CHAR)) {
                        mDataMDLP = gattCharacteristic;

                        Log.d("777", "Found MLDP data characteristics");
                    }
                    else if (uuid.equals(MLDP_CONTROL_PRIVATE_CHAR)) {
                        mControlMLDP = gattCharacteristic;
                        //bondedBL.createBond();
                        Log.d("777", "Found MLDP control characteristics");
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    final TextView connection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                                    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {                                      
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            connection.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                        }
                                    }, 3000);

                                }
                        });

                    }
                    final int characteristicProperties = gattCharacteristic.getProperties();
                    if ((characteristicProperties & (BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY)) > 0) {
                        mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(gattCharacteristic, true);
                        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = gattCharacteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(CHARACTERISTIC_NOTIFICATION_CONFIG));
                        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                        mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
                    }
                    if ((characteristicProperties & (BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_INDICATE)) > 0) {
                        mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(gattCharacteristic, true);
                        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = gattCharacteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(CHARACTERISTIC_NOTIFICATION_CONFIG));
                        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
                        mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
                    }
                    if ((characteristicProperties & (BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE)) > 0) {
                        gattCharacteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
                    }
                    if ((characteristicProperties & (BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE)) > 0) {
                        gattCharacteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if (mDataMDLP == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "findMldpGattService found no MLDP service");
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which part takes a lot of time? Scanning, connecting, enumerating the services etc?

Comment: @Codo Enumerating the services